# methods for list filters

Tags: lists, filter

I have a list of products in an android app, and I want to find a way to let user filter the results and narrow them. But, my filter has at least 3 or 4 entries including a `TextView` and some `DropDown` like items, so I do not want to place them all within the main page that contains the aforementioned list. So, What would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

A *well labelled* popup dialog for filter settings which is opened via a  filter settings button and dims the background but does not completely hide or cover it

Here's an excellent example from the FourSquare iPhone and Android apps. The Android app uses the same filter settings button (but at bottom right) and a standard Android popup. Note the personalisation of the messages.

[image]
[image]